# Yii2 remove form name from url parameters

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-form

I use Yii2 forms and after submit my URL looks like:

```
http://example.com/recommendations/index?RecommendationSearch%5Bname%5D=&RecommendationSearch%5Bstatus_id%5D=&RecommendationSearch%5Btype%5D=0&RecommendationSearch%5Bcreated_at%5D=&sort=created_at
```

As you may seem each parameter contains form name `RecommendationSearch`. How to remove this `RecommendationSearch` from parameters in order to get URL url like the following:

```
http://example.com/recommendations/?name=&status_id=&type=0&created_at=&sort=created_at
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override [`formName()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#formName()-detail) in your `RecommendationSearch` model to return empty string:

```
public function formName() {
    return '';
}
```